# Latex renders "Script file ./input.markdown.lua not found" error into pdf

Tags: pdf, templates, pandoc, lua

I am using this command line (batch file):

```
.\pandoc.exe --pdf-engine-opt=-shell-escape --from=markdown --output=test.pdf mini.md --template .\templates\test.template
```

with this input file

```
#Testbook

Testline
```

using this template

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[top=1.25in, bottom=1.25in, left=1in, right=3in]{geometry}
\usepackage[inlineFootnotes=true,pipeTables=true]{markdown}

% Language, Smart-convert " to guillemets
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[inlineFootnotes=true,pipeTables=true]{markdown}

% Meta
\title{Testtitle}
\author{Testname}
\date{Testdate}

\begin{document}
\markdownInput{test.md}
\end{document}
```

and all I get as a pdf is this:
[image]

Why is that? The only reference to this error I could find was here https://github.com/Witiko/markdown/issues/6 which to me does not seem to apply here.

Comment: Why do you use `pandoc` in this case? You should run just `lualatex template.tex`.

Comment: `pandoc` seems to take much better care of several aspects such as tables and footnotes in my application. I have tried without pandoc but it just does not work as well. I will try again but would really prefer the `pandoc` route.

Comment: Markdown package has several extensions for footnotes and tables, that might help. If you really want to use Pandoc, you should modify your template to not use the Markdown package, specify a placeholder where the converted LaTeX code will be inserted, and compile directly the Markdown document.

Comment: @michal.h21 Thanks for the reminder. I realized tonight that during all this learning, copying and pasting I had omitted setting up the placeholder for these examples. I still don't know what that message up there means but I realize that part of my execution is just flawed.